# a simple client-server application for android

Tags: android, windows, linux, client-server

I want to write a very simple application (maybe it is not so simple). I want to run application on my PC (either windows or linux) from the android phone. lets say I will have couple of buttons on my phone's screen and each button will open an application, say notepad or calculator. Or even better I will have an application on my computer screen (this will also be written) lets say 8 buttons on the appliaction and I will have same 8 buttons on my phone screen which will imitate as if I am clicking those buttons on my computer screen. I do not want to do this like GMote does by controlling mouse (touchpad).

I have some programming experience but not in Android. I dont know where to start so I will appreciate if someone could head me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance...

cs

Answer (score 1):

The actual coding of this is fairly simple to accomplish.  Basically you just open a TCP/IP connection and send and receive representations of keys and responses.  There's a few things to learn about permitting easy reconnect when connection is lost and the like, but basically it's all vanilla TCP/IP client server programming in either native or java code, in the context of both the phone and the PC.

What's more complicated is the network topology that can connect the phone and the PC.

If they are both on the same wifi network it's pretty easy, just connect to the PC by its IP address.

But if you want to use the phone's 3g connection, it will be much harder.  Chances are the PC you want to connect is not reachable from the external internet due to a combination of firewalls and/or network address translation, so the phone can't directly contact it.  You may need to connect them by means of an internet server visible to both the phone and your [cable/dsl/corporate network] - connected PC.

Another possibility might be to get a bluetooth dongle for the PC and connect to it that way, though there can be a lot to learn about getting the PC side of the bluetooth interface working right and the APIs to program against it.

Comment: thanks for the response. connection through the wifi is just fine. I will have an application on the PC side which will receive commands from the android and perform a certain task. is there an example you can recommend for the TCP/IP connectivity you mentioned? Thanks again...

Comment: The most functional example is an open source program called netcat, it still compiles and would be extremely useful as a substitute for either end in testing your work, but it's in a somewhat archaic style of C.  There are lots of other client/server examples around the net in both C and java.  But look at the netcat source to see how they set up the REUSEADDR flag to make reconnection work, which lots of others forget.  It also sounded like you were aware of an android app that did something similar but not exactly what you need - if that's open source you may want to look at that.

Comment: great, I will look at that. Right now I am trying to familiarize myself with android sdk/eclipse. I used VB and C++ but new to Java and android. thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple at all. Probably in fact one of the more complicated things you could possibly do on android. Your description is extremely vague and it looks like you've put very little actual effort into this.

If you really want to pursue this, take a look at http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I looked at the VNC viewer, it looks nice however it is for controlling the whole desktop. I just want to send a command to the PC and I want to have that command to be received by an application I wrote on the PC end. Lets say I have a button on my android screen and when I tap that button, application on the PC receives it and opens up the calculator or turns up the volume etc.